# Перенести значения полей из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, mysql

Уважаемые SQL-щики))) для кого-то этот вопрос покажется элементарным, уж извините...

Дано:
**table1**, **table2** - таблицы одной базы
**table1.name**, **table2.name** - поля с одинаковыми значениями соответственно
**table1.pole1**, **table1.pole2** - заполненные поля
**table2.pole1**, **table2.pole2** - пустые поля

Задача:
Как вы уже поняли, написать запрос, копирующий значения полей **pole1** и **pole2** соответствующих строк из **table1** в **table2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table2 t2, table1 t1
set t2.pole1=t1.pole1,t2.pole2=t1.pole2
where t1.name=t2.name;
select * from table2;
```

Comment: как часы. Благодарствую!